# Горизонтальная прокрутка для GridView

Tags: java, android

Есть код галереи которая горизонтально прокручивается. Ширину задаю исходя из количества фоток `android:layout_width="500dp"`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="500dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="130dp"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:columnWidth="100dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:numColumns="9"
                android:horizontalSpacing="1dp"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawHorizontalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                android:stretchMode="none"
                android:verticalSpacing="1dp">
            </GridView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Дальше я вставляю ее фрагментом где мне нужно.

```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/fr_image_grid"
       android:name="com.nostra13.universalimageloader.sample.fragment.ImageGridFragment"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Я хочу использовать эту галерею в другом месте с другими фотками. Я вставляю фрагмент в другое место, передаю фотки, вроде все работает. Но у меня там не 5 фоток а больше, а так как длина у меня уже задана в `500dp`, то в новой галереи только 5 фото отображаются.
Как мне изменить ширину `LinearLayout`? 
Пробовал задавать `wrap_content` вместо `500dp` не получилось, отображается только одна фотка.

Comment: Всю эту дикую вложенность контейнеров нужно убрать, оставив только `LinearLayout` с размерами `match_parent` и в нем `GridView` с параметром `wrap_content` по высоте/ Фрагмент тоже должен быть с размерами `match_parent`

Comment: Сделал как вы написали, длину теперь норм выставляет. А как теперь сделать прокрутку горизонтальную?

Comment: Для горизонтальной прокрутки [использовать HorizontalGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33373409) из библиотеки поддержки

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.